# How to look at a cell's text and assign different values depending on what the text is

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

This is a classic IF ELSE statement problem but I deciding to just use a `LOOKUP` so it's easier to understand:

I want to look at the value of cell D1230 and have the following instructions:

```
If text is either: "CE BSW", "Datalinks", "CE SAC, Infra"  -> Assign "1"
If text is either: "PFT","CFT"  -> Assign "2"
If text is either: "AHCC","SIC (Spark Igntion Controls)","Fuel Systems" –> Assign "3"
```

This is my formula:

```
=LOOKUP(D1230,{"CE BSW";"Datalinks";"CE SAC, Infra";"PFT";"CFT";"AHCC";"SIC"},{"1";"1";"1";"2";"2";"3";"3"})
```

Unfortunately it's not working and I'm getting a `#N/A` error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your formula works for me, unless the lookup cell (D1230) is blank or contains a value other one of the listed ones in which case I get N/A.  But that is what you would expect.

Comment: With LOOKUP, you will need to order the lookup items in ascending order or switch to an INDEX/MATCH and do not put `""` around numbers, it will store them as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use IFS:

```
=IFS(
    OR(D1230={"CE BSW", "Datalinks", "CE SAC, Infra"}),1,
    OR(D1230={"PFT","CFT"}),2,
    OR(D1230={"AHCC","SIC (Spark Igntion Controls)","Fuel Systems"}),3,
    TRUE,"")
```

Another method:

```
=INDEX({1;1;1;2;2;3;3},
    MATCH(D1230,{"CE BSW";"Datalinks";"CE SAC, Infra";"PFT";"CFT";"AHCC";"SIC"},0))
```

The difference between this and your LOOKUP is that LOOKUP requires the lookup range be sorted ascending.  MATCH with `0` as the third criterion will look for an exact match and does not require them to be sorted.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: Everything is working excet for PFT, CFT is not setting it to 2

Comment: This looks for complete match, as in there cannot be any other characters even spaces in the cells.

Comment: One last thing, when it sets the result, it places the number in the left-side of the cell. Is there a way to place it on the right-side of the cell?

Comment: That is a format thing.  Just align the cell to the right.